# Sprig request Getting 414 Request-URI Too Long

Tags: multi-site, plugin-sprig

I have sprig components on multiple pages, Some are working fine but some get '414 Request-URI Too Long '

Looking at the networks tab, it sends many elementId={ids}&CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN={token} after my params and before siteId which is it's usual request pattern

The number of elementId and CSRF_TOKEN is the number of items the sprig component is showing currently.[image: Issue with get request 414 error, sending element ids and CSRF token]

[image: Working fine, has no elementIds or tokens attached to the ger request url]

Answer (score 1):

There’s not enough detail, nor a specific enough question, to provide a solid answer. But in general, you’ll want to limit the number of parameters submitted, since the length of the URI is limited for GET requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have attached 2 images to better explain what I have found when it works and when it has errors.

The number of ids and GH_CSRF_TOKEN is the exact number of items returned by the previous query.